# Why can I not chain logical comparisons in an if statement?

Tags: matlab, if-statement, logical-operators

I'm trying to execute a block of code if one of several conditions is met.  Again, for clarity, if *any* of the conditions are true, I'd like for the code to execute (chain of logical ORs).

When I type this code into Matlab:

```
if strmatch(T,'Sd') || strmatch(T,'SuperDev') || ...
        strmatch(T,'lrnTrialVD') || strmatch(T,'lrnTrialVIS') || ...
        strmatch(T,'lrnTrialTARGET') || strmatch(T,'lrnTrialAUD')
```

I get this error:

```
??? Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.
```

Can someone please tell me where I've gone wrong?

/blz

EDIT:  I used the wrong function.  strcmp is what I meant to use!

Comment: You can use `strmatch`, and even have a cell array for all your strings, but you need to use `any` around the `strmatch` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is because the return value of `strmatch()` is an array, not a scalar, and `||` might not be defined on array arguments. I don't have MATLAB in front of me (only Octave), but does `[1, 2, 3] || [4, 5, 6, 7]` work for you?

Additonally, it would be better to match a regular expression like `(Sd|SuperDev|lrnTrial(VD|VIS|TARGET|AUD))` which is a bit more compact, more readable, and only needs to inspect the string 'T' once (not six times.)

This would look like:

```
octave-3.2.4.exe:10> T1 = "Sd"
T1 = Sd
octave-3.2.4.exe:11> T2 = "Lollipop"
T2 = Lollipop
octave-3.2.4.exe:12> regexp(T1,"(Sd|SuperDev|lrnTrial(VD|VIS|TARGET|AUD))" )
ans =  1
octave-3.2.4.exe:13> regexp(T2,"(Sd|SuperDev|lrnTrial(VD|VIS|TARGET|AUD))" )
ans = [](1x0)
```

Comment: Indeed!  I just realized I meant to use strmcp!

Comment: In general, though, even `strcmp` shouhld only be used when you want to check if a string is exactly the same as one other string. If you want to check if `T` is one of six allowable strings, use a regexp.

Comment: @Li-uang Yip:  thanks for the regexp tip, it works beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

`strmatch` doesn't necessarily return something which can be converted to a logical scalar value.  It might, for example, return a vector of match locations which does not convert without further effort on your part.  It's all there in the error message and the product documentation, it really is !

Comment: Oh christ, how embarassing!  I meant to use strcmp ...!

Comment: No need to call me Christ though I appreciate the sentiment.